# Aligning sections to the left

Tags: sectioning, horizontal-alignment

I am writing my thesis and using `\documentclass{thesis.tex}`, how do I left align only my sections and subsections without it affecting the chapter which is centered

Comment: You mean the section and subsection headings?

Comment: There are scores of `thesis.cls` around. Can you point to a net address for the one you're using?

Comment: yes i mean sections and subsections aligning to the left. Not familiar with other scores of thesis.cls. just using  \documentclass{thesis}.

Comment: @chris I understand what you're doing. But it's clearly a local class file and without seeing what it does it's impossible to help. If it's an official class of your university, you shouldn't be modifying its style.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using the `thesis.cls` in the `contrib/thesis` directory of CTAN, which indeed does produce centered headings.  (This is the only file of that name on CTAN and seems to be included in the MikTex distribution, but not TeXLive.)

There is a `nocenter` package option that affects headings at all levels.  But to adjust just sections and subsections, it appears that you need to cut and paste code from the class file (the full path to which is give in the log file).  Specifically you need to redefine `\section` and `\subsection`.  As these commands use code containing the @ character you will need to include this in between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`.

A minimal example showing this is:

```
\documentclass{thesis}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                               {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                               {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                               {\raggedright
                               \reset@font\s@font}}
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
                                 {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                 {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                 {\raggedright
                                  \reset@font\ss@font}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
A full line of text to pad out the example and show the spacing is as
requested in the posted question.
\section{Middle}
A full line of text to pad out the example and show the spacing is as
requested in the posted question.
\subsection{Last}
A full line of text to pad out the example and show the spacing is as
requested in the posted question.

\end{document}
```

[image: Sample output]